# Транспонация датафрейма в питон

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

В python есть DataFrame такого формата:

| Дата | Источник 1 | Источник 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 нояб | 23 | 50 |
| 7 нояб | 43 | 87 |

Нужно заголовки таблицы поместить в столбцы в соответсвии со столбцом "дата", чтобы датафрейм получился следующей структуры:

| Дата | Название | установки |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 нояб | Источник 1 | 23 |
| 6 нояб | Источник 2 | 50 |
| 7 нояб | Источник 1 | 43 |
| 7 нояб. | Источник 2 | 87 |

Как можно это воспроизвести?

Comment: Это куда-то в сторону `pivot_table` видимо, но конкретно не скажу, нужно разбираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом `melt`:

```
res = pd.melt(df,id_vars="Дата", value_vars=["Источник 1", "Источник 2"],
              var_name="Название", value_name="Установки").sort_values("Дата")
```

res:

```
     Дата    Название  Установки
0  6 нояб  Источник 1         23
2  6 нояб  Источник 2         50
1  7 нояб  Источник 1         43
3  7 нояб  Источник 2         87
```